# .NET web forms update site content server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have website used by hundred of viewers every day. One of the pages has a timer that ticks every 10 seconds, when it does so it gets the latest data from the database and updates the screen.

The problem i have is that a high number of users and a high number of database connections takes its toll on the server.

Is there a better way of doing this? Updating server side and all users would benefit from the latest data but only the server is carrying out the calls every 10 seconds and not by every user?

Comment: I think it depends; how much has typically changed between ten second intervals?

Comment: regardless of changes, every 10 seconds each user makes 5+ database requests, so by 100 users this is 500 database requests every 10 seconds. It would be great for the server to do this and therefore keep the database connections to just 5 every 10 seconds and not growing with number of users.

Comment: Are you using ajax + webservices? That way you can at least lighten up the load on the server by not creating post backs and running through the full .net life cycle. If you aren't. I would suggest using AJAX + webservices and update your html using jquery/javascript.

Comment: Any examples of that Matthew?

Comment: SignalR is definitely a good option to get the control to the server. But first start with implementing caching on the server. That would save quite some database calls.

Comment: Jacco brings up a good point. Implementing memcache or any distributed caching would reduce db calls. Then you just need to update memcache when you make updates to the db.

Answer (score 1):

[SignalR](http://signalr.net/) is the way you'll want to go. Right now, your application is probably loading a page. Then you got some jQuery that probably sets a timer for 10 seconds. Then your timer is kicking off and you're probably doing an ajax call to get refreshed data, then putting that refreshed data into a `<div>` or something.

So essentially, every 10 seconds, your back end is calling your SQL server, doing some kind of `SELECT` statement, then the data from the SQL Server is being transmitted to your application server, where you are taking that data, transforming into displayable data.

[SignalR](http://signalr.net/), on the other hand works differently. It uses push technology. Push technology works like this. Lets say you have 5 people visiting your page right now. One person (person A) is doing something that saves something to the database. No one else is seeing this data though yet. But SignalR will send a signal out to everyone else (or just the people in which this database save affects) that says "Hey! There is newer data available. You should update now". The other people connected do an ajax call and get the refreshed data. And viola! The other 4 people now have updated data on their screen!

I hope I explained this clearly enough for you to understand! [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/) wrote a good [introduction](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx) to SignalR.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the setInterval() to fire an ajax function every 10 seconds.

```
window.setInterval("javascript function", milliseconds);
```

the javascript function would be similar to

```
function GetLatest(){
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '../Services/UpdateService.asmx/GetLatest',
      data: '',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function (data) {
              //use the data.d to get the info passed back from webservice. then 
              add your logic to update your html
      },
      error: function () {
         //catch any bad data
      } 
     });
}
```

your backend method should look like this. Object is whatever your objcet is

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public Object GetLatest()
        {
            Object obj= new Object ();

            obj.FirstName = "Dave";
            obj.LastName = "Ward";

     return obj;
    }
```

Comment: The above solution at least minimizes postbacks from your server side. If you're using MVC / Web forms this will help. Just adjust the code accordingly for which framework you're using. The above is with web forms.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered having your server side code cache the data for that 10 seconds. Cache it and set it's expiration for 10 seconds. That way, everyone gets the same information for 10 seconds and then the first after that 10 retrieves a new data set and then caches it. That way, only the first person to refresh causes a DB query, the rest get data up to 10 seconds old. Something like this:

```
Cache.Insert(key, data, Nothing, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10), TimeSpan.Zero)
```

I guess this is assuming that the users are all getting the same data at each poll. If they are all getting unique datasets, this won't cut it for you.